What is the function of this clause in terms of grammar?
Today I encountered the sentence:
"The drinkers at the other tables paused, glasses half-way to their lips, and stared with disbelief"
What is the function of "glasses half-way to their lips" in the sentence above? Is it a noun clause or how is it even called in terms of grammar?
For me, it's similar to something like adverbial or prepositional phrase that modifies a verb like "The drinkers at the other tables paused, in one moment, and stared with disbelief". But it's clearly not the case. So, what do you think it is?

"The drinkers at the other tables paused, [had] glasses half-way to their lips, and stared with disbelief."  a compound sentence in my reading.

@Kinschichi It's a clause whose function is that of supplement, here a kind of interpolation, a non-integrated element. More specifically, it's the verbless analogue of the non-finite clause "(their) glasses held half-way to their lips". Supplements are not modifiers; rather, they have an 'anchor' that they relate to, in this case the noun phrase "The drinkers at the other tables".
